# Add css to first div when it have same divs?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 popups, first one when open a new page, and the second one when user click in a link. Tried using first-child to add some css to all button in div1, but it also adds to div2. I want to button A, B, C, D add width 50%, how can I fix it?

$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane:first-child .button").width(50%);

Div1:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane">
 <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset" >
 <button type="button" class="ui-button"  role="button">A</button>
 <button type="button" class="ui-button"  role="button">B</button>
 <button type="button" class="ui-button"  role="button">C</button>
 <button type="button" class="ui-button"  role="button">D</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

DIV 2:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane">
 <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset" >
 <button type="button" class="ui-button"  role="button">E</button>
 <button type="button" class="ui-button"  role="button">F</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add buttons to specific id attribute

Comment: my ui-dialog-buttonpane is auto generate from system , so i can't change it

Answer (score 2):

`:first-child` will target all `.ui-dialog-buttonpane` that are first child of their parent. wherease you want to target first `.ui-dialog-buttonpane` on page. Use `:first` or `:eq(0)` instead of `:first-child` for this:

```
$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane:first .ui-button").width(50%);
```

Comment: still can't change the button's width :(

Comment: There is no element with class `button` :)

Comment: @user3064132: as A.Wolff pointed. here is incorrect selector to target. eiher use class selector `.ui-button` or use tagname seector `button`

Answer (score 1):

Small correction, You are applying width for the `.button` but the class name is `.ui-button`. Try any of the following codes, will work for your query.

`$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane:first .ui-button").css("width","50%");`

OR

`$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane:first button").css("width","50%");`

Comment: so weird .. when use your code it apply to my DIV2 , may be the reason because it's a popup?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS its as simple as

```
.ui-dialog-buttonpane:first-child .ui-button{
   width:50%;
}
```

[Working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/woquripahu/edit?html,css,js,output)

In jQuery

```
$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane:first-child .ui-button").width('50%');
```

[Working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xofujosata/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: We don't know if first `.ui-dialog-buttonpane` is the `:first-child` of its parent

Comment: @A.Wolff : My assumption for the above came from how OP tried it with jQuery syntax and included :first-child in it.

Comment: Ya but i guess OP was wrong trying to use `:first-child`, as he was wrong using `.button`. As a sdie note, in CSS4, it would be possible: `.ui-dialog-buttonpane:not(.ui-dialog-buttonpane ~ .ui-dialog-buttonpane) .ui-button`

Comment: Totally agree. would wait for OP to clarify on this.

Comment: sr but i can't use css because it will change to another page

Answer (score 0):

In pure CSS, if `.ui-dialog-buttonpane` are siblings, you could use:

```css
.ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-button {
  width: 50%;
}

.ui-dialog-buttonpane ~ .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-button {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<span>something else</span>
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane">
  <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button type="button" class="ui-button" role="button">A</button>
    <button type="button" class="ui-button" role="button">B</button>
    <button type="button" class="ui-button" role="button">C</button>
    <button type="button" class="ui-button" role="button">D</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane">
  <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button type="button" class="ui-button" role="button">E</button>
    <button type="button" class="ui-button" role="button">F</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sr but i can't use css because it will affect to another page . I just want to change this page

Comment: @user3064132 Just add style tag to specific page... Just like you will do for script. Your comment doesn't make sense, sorry